# Apache Spark eventLog configuration on Windows Giving error

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, apache-spark, event-log

I am using Spark 1.5 on Windows. I haven't installed any separate binaries of Hadoop.

I running a Master and a single worker.
It's a simple HelloWorld Program as below :

```
package com.java.spark;



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;

public class HelloWorld implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7926281781224763077L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Local mode
    //SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HelloWorld").setMaster("local");
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HelloWorld").setMaster("spark://192.168.1.106:7077")
                                         .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
                                         .set("spark.eventLog.dir", "file:///D:/SparkEventLogsHistory");
                                        //.set("spark.eventLog.dir", "/work/");
//tried many combinations above but all gives error.
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        String[] arr = new String[] { "John", "Paul", "Gavin", "Rahul", "Angel" };
    List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(arr);
    JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = ctx.parallelize(inputList);
    inputRDD.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {

        public void call(String input) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(input);

        }
    });

}
}
```

The exception I am getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program    "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:188)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil$CygPathCommand.<init>(FileUtil.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.makeShellPath(FileUtil.java:438)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.makeShellPath(FileUtil.java:465)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.execCommand(RawLocalFileSystem.java:592)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:420)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:541)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at com.java.spark.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

16/04/01 20:13:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this exception, so that Spark can pick the eventLogs from local directory.

If I dont give configure eventLog.dir then exception changes to :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/H:/tmp/spark-events does not exist
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:541)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at com.java.spark.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:28)
```

Comment: You should verify that the hadoop is properly configured on windows before running the spark application. Check this link for how to configure hadoop on windows : http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/

Comment: I had mentioned that I have not installed hadoop. Spark doesn't need installation of Hadoop. I am running Spark in local mode on windows and runs fine.